# Can you make french toast without eggs and gluten?

Tags: bread, eggs, gluten-free, breakfast

I have an allergy to eggs and gluten. But before getting the allergy my favorite breakfast food was french toast. I've tried gluten free bread dipped in soy milk but it's not the same and doesn't taste very good either. Is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Egg replacements are an option depending on where you live and what products are available, but from what I hear they don't produce a similar result to eggs. Most egg-free french toast recipes use applesauce mixed with milk or yogurt and a bit of sugar for dipping, and from what I've heard they work well.

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of recipes out there for gluten free bread.  So, I'll assume that you can buy or make that part.  The tricky part is going to be the egg replacement.  The eggs affect both the flavor and texture.  I don't see how to exactly replicate the effect without using eggs, but you might be able to make something that's still delicious even if it's a bit different.

If you search the Internet for "vegan french toast," you'll find a lot of ideas on how to approximate the custardy texture without eggs.  Some of the recipes I found use chia seeds or mashed bananas for texture.  I'd be tempted to add some butter to help with the flavor.

Comment: Ok, I never thought about looking for vegan options. Thank you

Comment: "Search the Internet" isn't exactly an answer, is it?

Comment: @Stephie To be fair, this answer goes on to mention chia seeds and mashed bananas as possible egg replacements, so I think it is an answer. It's not a great one since there's not much evaluation of how well those might work, but I think it's still an answer.

Comment: There is always value in suggesting good search terms.